# jQuery to trigger CSS3 button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this CSS3 enter button
[here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2568/enter/enter.html):

If you click it, it seems like it's pressed. I want to achieve the same effect (probably using jQuery), by pressing the enter key physically on my keyboard.

I did something like this: (sorry if it's completely wrong, I don't do jQuery at all)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("enter").keypress(function(event){
       if(event.keyCode == 13){
         $(this).toggleClass(".button-clicked");
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

The CSS selector for the unpressed button is:
`.button` and `.button.orange {}`

The CSS selector for the pressed button is:
`.button:active, .button-clicked {}`

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>I haven't tested this, but I think you should be able to do something like</s>

I *have* just tested this (and linked to a demo, below the jQuery), and it works pretty well:

```
$('body').keydown(
    function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) { // enter
            $('buttonSelector').addClass('button-clicked');
        }
    }).keyup(
    function(e){
        if (e.which == 13) { // enter
            $('buttonSelector').removeClass('button-clicked');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9pY77/1/).

With this the keydown causes the button to appear pressed so long as the enter key is pressed, and, on release, triggers the `keyup()` handler, changing the style of the button so as to appear un-clicked.

Refined the above, somewhat, using `on()`, though having to use an `if/else if` statement to check the function type:

```
$('body').on('keydown keyup', function(e) {
    if (e.type == 'keydown') {
        if (e.which == 13) { // enter
            $('#button').addClass('button-clicked');
        }
    }
    else if (e.type == 'keyup') {
        if (e.which == 13) { // enter
            $('#button').removeClass('button-clicked');
        }
    }
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/9pY77/2/).

References:

- [`keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/).
- [`keyup()`](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/).
- [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/).
- [`removeClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Comment: The only thing I noticed is that if you change `$('body')` to `$(document)` then you can press enter while only the page is focused. It seems that selecting the `body` element requires some element on the page to be selected to catch the `keydown`/`keyup` events. **UPDATE** I observed this in Firefox 7; I.E. 8 and Chrome 15 worked as expected.

Comment: That's absolutely true, of course. And is, I suppose, implicit in the use of the selector itself (the event being matched to that element, rather than the document as a whole).

Comment: sorry, I'm still testing your solution. your fiddle would be perfect, for some reason it is not working for me yet.

Comment: @user1072354: really? What's going wrong with it? Are there any errors in the JavaScript console, or showing up when you hit the 'JS Lint' button on JS Fiddle?

Comment: the <button> tag is necessary instead of the <div>? and the id selectors intead of class? I used class selectors because I might have more buttons on the page.
EDIT: sorry, the fiddle works fine, mine doesn't:
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2568/enter/enter.html

Comment: No, you can use any selectors you like; and it'll still work. Could you post a JS Fiddle of your current implementation, and I'll take a look there? That way I can see, and edit, your current mark-up/JavaScript in-place.

Comment: I would, but if I insert the page into fiddle it works, when I test it the browser it doesn't. It's strange to me.

Comment: Then it seems that something else on your page/in your script is interfering. Check variable names, and see if there's any `return false` or `e.stopPropagation()` calls in the page/script that might be obscuring things.

Comment: okay, I have found the problem. if I change `$('body')` to `$(document)` (as @Jasper suggested) then it works like a charm. 
thank you guys so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to apply the `keypress` to an `<enter></enter>` element (which doesn't exist), try doing this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $("body").keypress(function(event){
       if(event.keyCode == 13){
         $(".button").toggleClass("button-clicked");
       }
     });
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Check your toggleClass syntax. I don't think you need the `.` (dot).

Answer (score 0):

Close but how about this:

```
//bind to the `keydown` event when the `document` is focused
$(document).on('keydown', function (event) {

    //if enter is pressed
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

        //add the `.button-clicked` class to any element with the `.button` class
        $('.button').addClass('button-clicked');
    }
}).on('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {

        $('.button').removeClass('button-clicked');
    }
});
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/T5yEu/2/

Notice that I added `!important` to the `.button-clicked` class on several of the rules to make sure they are added to the element.

Comment: thanks! in theory this works, but I want to simulate the whole button press thing with the release phase also. this one stucks pressed.

Comment: Then you bind to the `keyup` event as well. Check my edit: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/T5yEu/2/

Comment: @user1072354, bearing in mind that requirement, might I suggest that you look at my own suggestion, and see if that fits your need?